# Searching an item in a TcxTreeList in Borland C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-6

I am using C++ Builder 6. I have a TreeList with two columns and a TrzEdit and a Search Button. I want to find the item which i will type in the Edit field once i type something in the box. How can I display it?

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::BtnSearchClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  for (TcxTreeListNode* node = TreeList->TopNode ; node != NULL; node = node->GetNext())

  {
        String value = node->Values[PropertyName->ItemIndex];

        if ( value == Search->Text.c_str())
        {
          ShowMessage("Foundit");
        }
   }
}
```

Can someone please give an insight on how to do this? It works so far. I want to display all the items which matches the query keyword (even partialy)

I can find help with the new builder, but not the old one which i am using.

Is it possible with Tcxtreelist to make a node 'Visible' once a condition is matched and then mak eit invisible once the edit box is cleared. Does such functionality exists?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with exactly? Please be more specific. And why are you using `Text.c_str()` instead of just `Text`? If you want to do a partial comparison, look at the `AnsiString::Pos()` method, eg: `if (value.Pos(EdtMethodSearch->Text) != 0) { ... }`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thankyou so much for your reply.                                     
 1.What part are you having trouble with exactly?---> I want to display the elements which matches the search query( partial words should also return the elements containing those words).                                                                         2. Your suggestion 'if(value.Pos(EdtMethodSearch->Text) != 0)' did not work to give the elements that matches even partially. And thanks for pointing out the .c_str mistake.

Comment: Or once I enter anything in the edit box ( no need of button), the list should show the values containing the text in the edit box and when the editbox is emptied, the whole items should be made visble back. How can I implement this? Any leads will be of great help

Comment: "*I want to display the elements which matches the search query*" - you keep saying that, but you are not really explaining what exactly you want to display or how. "*                                                         Your suggestion did not work to give the elements that matches even partially*"- in what way exactly did it not work? Please clarify. Can you give an example?

Comment: "I want to display the elements which matches the search query"-> i have a TcxTreeList which has two columns. I want to implement a search functionality. For example, my list have the following items/elements in Column 1:- **find, findelement, findparser, parser, binaryfind**. So, when I type **'find'** in the Editbox, the Treelist should display the items **'find,findelement,findparser,binaryfind'**.

Comment: you didn't answer my question about why my code didn't work for you. So let's start even simpler - does iterating the tree work correctly, and does reading `node->Values[ColPropertyName->ItemIndex]` return the values you want to search in?

Comment: When I use, your code suggestion here: `for (TcxTreeListNode* node = MethodGridnew->TopNode ; node != NULL; node = node->GetNext())

  {


        String value = node->Values[ColPropertyName->ItemIndex];

        if(value.Pos(EdtMethodSearch->Text) != 0)
        {
           
           ShowMessage("Foundit");

        }

  }`  the list moves to the item containing that search word and only one element(the first one matching the query keyword) can be spotted. And it doesn't work with both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: `AnsiString::Pos()` is case sensitive. If you want to do a case insensitive search, you will have to convert all of the strings to the same case when comparing them, eg: `String search = EdtMethodSearch->Text.LowerCase(); ... if (value.LowerCase().Pos(search) != 0) ...` Alternatively, use a case insensitive search function, like [`Strutils::AnsiContainsText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.AnsiContainsText): `if (AnsiContainsText(value, EdtMethodSearch->Text))` (not sure if that is available in BCB6, I'll have to check that in the morning)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Now, my query comparison works. Now I have to display the matching items in the list when a query word is typed in the EditBox. Any suggestions for this? Righ now, what i have in mins is to delete the nodes in the list which doesnt have the query keyword and when the EditBox is emptied, it should be added back.

Comment: Or, make the nodes matching the search keyword 'Visible' and others 'invisisble' and tehn on clearing the word, the list load backs. Is this possible in TcxTreelist???

Comment: I will add this as a seperate question in stack overflow so that everyone can follow

Comment: yes, that is what you need to do